# MongoDB - $pull not working on Number array

Tags: mongodb

I have a JSON document like the below one. I would like to remove the matching element from the arrays.

```
{ 
    "_id" : NumberInt(1), 
    "fruits" : [
        "pears", 
        "bananas"
    ], 
    "vegetables" : [
        "carrots", 
        "celery", 
        "squash", 
        "carrots"
    ], 
    "ids" : [
        NumberLong(2825459592), 
        NumberLong(328257222163), 
        NumberLong(825544354), 
        NumberLong(3282580412308), 
        NumberLong(28254518083), 
        NumberLong(32825684682), 
        NumberLong(3282574078116), 
        NumberLong(32825709226), 
        NumberLong(328255745773)
    ]
}
```

From String array, The below update works.

```
db.test.update(
    {},
    { $pull: { fruits: { $in: [ "pears" ] }} },
    { multi: true }
   )
```

From Number array, The below update doesnt work. No error and not removing.

```
db.test.update(
    {},
    { $pull: { ids: { $in: [ 28254518083 ] }} },
    { multi: true }
)
```

I am using MongoChef's IntelliShell for executing the above commands.

Comment: what is your mongodb version?

Comment: I am using 3.2.11 version.

Answer (score 0):

This was a known issue, fixed in Mongo 3.2.10. I am able to reproduce the issue on 3.2.9, but not on 3.2.14. Refer [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-16801)

Comment: I am using 3.2.11 version. But still this is there.